# How can i adjust this code to python 3 for palindrome numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

```
# Python program to count and 
# print all palindrome numbers in a list.

def palindromeNumbers(list_a): 

    c = 0

    # loop till list is not empty
    for i in list_a:             

        # Find reverse of current number
        t = i
        rev = 0
        while t > 0:
            rev = rev * 10 + t % 10
            t = t / 10

        # compare rev with the current number
        if rev == i:
            print (i),
            c = c + 1

    print
    print ("Total palindrome nos. are" +  str(c))
    print

def main():

    list_a = [10, 121, 133, 155, 141, 252] 
    palindromeNumbers(list_a)

    list_b = [ 111, 220, 784, 565, 498, 787, 363]
    palindromeNumbers(list_b)                     

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()  # main function call
```

This code, obtained from
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/all-palindrome-numbers-in-a-list/, has been written in Python 2.

When I run this program in Python 3.6 it returns the value as 0 for both lists.

Can someone tell me how to change it to be compatible with Python 3?

Comment: did you try using this: http://www.pythonconverter.com/

Comment: I tried it. It still returns the same value.check the difference here: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/index.php**(use the above code)

Comment: I posted an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the important changes between Python2 and Python3 is integer division, that in Python2 returns a truncated, integer result while in Python3 returns a floating point number.  To have a real integer division you have to use a double slash, `"//"`.

In summary, change the line `t = t/10` to `t = t//10`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have changed the code a bit using a different method to check if the number is the same reversed... I tried not to change too much of your code...

The function `reverse()` just returns the string given to it reversed...

If I'm not mistaken the function makes a list out of the `str` by `split` function then `[::-1]` gives the list reversed...

```
def reverse(str):
    return str[::-1]


def palindromeNumbers(list_a): 

    c = 0

    # loop till list is not empty
    for i in list_a:             

        # Find reverse of current number
        t = i
        t = int(reverse((str(t))))
        if t == i:
            c += 1

    print ("Total palindrome nos. are " +  str(c))


def main():

    list_a = [10, 121, 133, 155, 141, 252]
    palindromeNumbers(list_a)

    list_b = [ 111, 220, 784, 565, 498, 787, 363]
    palindromeNumbers(list_b)                    

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()             # main function call
```

Try it out! I hope you find this helpful...

Comment: added an edit to explain... if anyone has more info of how it works I'll be glad to hear!

Comment: Oh well, it works but it's totally different from the elegant algorithm used  in the original program... on the contrary it suffices to add a `/` to put back on track the original program!

Comment: correct! I did not keep the same algorithm... after seeing your answer I'm ashamed I didn't see that! thanks @gboffi!

Answer (score 0):

I first converted the number to an iterable string str(i). Then I shortened the for loop by only comparing the first half of the number t[a] to the second half of the number t[~a], and then using all() to check that all of the comparisons were true. (using Python 3.6.8)

```
for i in list_a:             

    # convert interger to iterable string
    t = str(i)

    # compare first half of the number to second half of the number
    if all([t[a]==t[~a] for a in range(len(t)//2)]):
        print (i),
        c = c + 1
```